# Check for empty argument Python

Tags: python, sys

I'm having two problems with arguments in my program, the first problem is that I'm trying to print an error if no arguments are passed to the program and also I'm trying to instead having to use -n which stands for 'no argument' to actually not have to pass any argument to load the file into the program, I want it to just run like `python3 program.py file file2 file3` instead of using `python3 -n file file2 file3` etc.. I have commented out what I tried to check for the argument if the argument is just the program file [0] to exit

```
def main():

    script = sys.argv[0]
    action = sys.argv[1]
    noargfile = sys.argv[1:]
    filenames = sys.argv[2:]
    OutContent = filenames or noargfile

    #Load files with arguments -d & --default
    print("Loading Files....", sys.argv[1:])

    for arg in filenames:
        try:
            myfile = open(arg, "r")
            fileContent = myfile.readlines()
            myfile.close()
            OutContent = OutContent + fileContent

            #if len(sys.argv) == script:
                #print("No Argument")
                #sys.exit(0)

            if action == '--default':
                counter = 0 # set a counter to 0 
                for line in OutContent: #for each line in load if the " 200 " is found add 1 to the counter and repeat until done. 
                    if re.findall(r"\s\b200\b\s", line):
                        counter += 1
                print("\nTotal of (Status Code) 200 request:", counter)
            elif action == '-d':
                counter = 0 # set a counter to 0 
                for line in OutContent: #for each line in load if the " 200 " is found add 1 to the counter and repeat until done. 
                    if re.findall(r"\s\b200\b\s", line):
                        counter += 1
                print("\nTotal of (Status Code) 200 request:", counter)
            elif action == '-n':
                menu(arg, OutContent)
        except OSError:
           print("File could not be opened " + filenames)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get an index out of range error, I don't understand why

```
File "program.py", line 161, in main
    action = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: you can catch the error by putting it into a `try` and `except` statement then if it caught an `IndexError` you can simply ignore it. But probably not the best way to do it right

Comment: You should use a more sophistcated arg parse like `argparse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to be first line in function main:

`if len(sys.argv)==1: sys.exit("error here")`

Comment: Why can't I do it after I assign sys.argv[1] to a variable? Also do you know how I would go about not having to use -n to load files? I tried just doing `elif noargfile:
                menu(arg, OutContent)`

Comment: Thanks I figure it out I was not paying attention at the fact that I have `filenames` starting at the third argument. I did `if filenames:
                menu(arg,OutContent)` Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't doing argument parsing yourself when there are already very good argument parses out there (there are probably 100 on pypy)

This little example uses `argparse` module. It takes `n` number of files and stores it as a list of strings in the variable `files`

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Load some files')
parser.add_argument('-f','--files', dest='files', nargs='+', help='<Required> Set flag', required=True)


args = parser.parse_args()
print args.files
```

**Usage:**

```
python myscript -f test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt
```

Here are more details on how to add more functionalities like `help` pages or make `required|optional` fields. https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html